# Circles cause pickle to surpass recursion limit?

Tags: python, recursion, pickle

I'm working on a video related project where I have superpixels and I have to keep track of each superpixel's "neighbors" (in a feature space, it doesn't really matter). So each superpixel object keeps an array of other superpixels.

Everything works fine, but when I try to pickle a list of all superpixels (The runtime for creating them is quite a while), pickle raises: "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".

I've tried setting the recursion limit higher, but it just results in python crashing, so I'm trying to understand what recursion pickle is talking about. 
Is this because superpixel_1 can hold superpixel_2 as a neighbor, and superpixel_2 can hold superpixel_1 as well, creating a circle?
If not, what is this recursion? My superpixel objects have nothing else recursive about them.

Also, this only happens when I'm trying to pickle a large (but reasonable) amount of superpixels objects. 600~ are stored with ease, while 15*600~ cause the crash.

Comment: The issue is most certainly this circular reference.  You could consider modifying your code to use weak references instead - that would eliminate the circular nature of the object tree.

Comment: The following answers the portion of your question that's about circular references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433963/can-pickle-handle-multiple-object-references

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit()` might be a practical way to increase the limit.

Comment: As I said, I already tried raising the recursion limit. It the thread you (NPE) posted it says that pickle can handle circular references, so what can be the problem?