# How to pickle objects with many views of same cython memoryview

Tags: cython, pickle

I have a number of objects that I am trying to pickle which all share the same (large) cython memoryview as an attribute.  Since the memoryviews are passed by reference, they all share the same memory and the implementation is memory efficient.

Now I need to pickle these objects and reload them while keeping the shared data shared (if the shared data becomes not shared then the file size blows up and it is impossible to read into memory).  Normally I think pickle recognizes shared data and just pickles/unpickles it once, but because memory views can't be pickled directly, they need to be converted to a numpy array in the **reduce** method for each object and pickle no longer recognizes that the data is shared.

Is there some way that I can maintain the shared data through the pickle/unpickle process?

A MWE follows:

```
import numpy as np    
import pickle

cdef class SharedMemory:  
    cdef public double[:, :] data

    def __init__(self, data):   
        self.data = data

    def duplicate(self):
        return SharedMemory(self.data)

    def __reduce__(self):   
        return self.__class__, (np.asarray(self.data),)


def main():   
    x = SharedMemory(np.random.randn(100, 100))

    duplicates = [x.duplicate() for _ in range(5)]

    cdef double* pointerx = &x.data[0, 0]
    cdef double* pointerd
    cdef double[:, :] ddata

    for d in duplicates:
        ddata = d.data 
        pointerd = &ddata[0, 0]
        if pointerd != pointerx:
            print('Memory is not shared')
        else:
            print('Memory is shared')

    print('pickling')
    with open('./temp.pickle', 'wb') as pfile:
        pickle.dump(x, pfile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        for d in duplicates:
            pickle.dump(d, pfile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    with open('./temp.pickle', 'rb') as pfile:
        nx = pickle.load(pfile)
        nd = []
        for d in duplicates:
            nd.append(pickle.load(pfile))

    ddata = nx.data
    cdef double* pointernx = &ddata[0, 0]

    for d in nd:
        ddata = d.data
        pointerd = &ddata[0, 0]
        if pointerd != pointernx:
            print('Memory is not shared')
        else:
            print('Memory is shared')
```

Put the above in a file test.pyx an cythonize with "cythonize -a -i test.pyx".  Then "export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH":." and run

```
from test import main
main()
```

from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two problems:

**First:** The shared objects are also shared after dump/load only if they where pickled in one go (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7434285/5769463)).

That means you need to do the following (or similar):

```
...
with open('./temp.pickle', 'wb') as pfile:
     pickle.dump((x,duplicates), pfile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
...
with open('./temp.pickle', 'rb') as pfile:
     nx, nd = pickle.load(pfile)
...
```

When you dump single objects, pickle isn't able to track identical objects - doing so would be an issue: objects with the same id between two `dump`-calls could be completely different objects or the same objects with different content!

**Second:** You should not create new objects, but pass the shared numpy-object in `__reduce__` (pickle doesn't look inside of a numpy-array to see, whether buffer is shared or not, but only at the id of the array):

```
def __reduce__(self):
    return self.__class__, (self.data.base,)
```

which will give you the desired result. `data.base` is a reference to the underlying original numpy-array (or whatever type, which must support pickling/unpickling, obviously).

---

**Warning:** As @DavidW has  rightly pointed out, additional considerations must be taken into account, when working with sliced memory-views - because in this case `base` might not be "the same" as the actual memory view.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is a good catch and would normally solve the issue but it still doesn't work in this case (I've updated the MWE to pickle this way but the results are still the same).  The problem is that in the `__reduce__` method the memoryview cannoth be pickled directly, therefore it must be made into a new numpy array object, which pickle thinks is different and thus pickle separately (check `np.asarray(x.data) is np.asarray(duplicates[0].data)` is False, so pickle thinks they're different)

Comment: @Andrew, true - I have changed `reduce` as well in my code, but have forgotten to add this detail to the answer - now it is done.

Comment: Awesome, that second part was key.  Don't know why i didn't think about returning base instead

Comment: It's probably worth saying that if you do any slicing to make the memoryviews then `.base` is likely to give you the wrong answer. Some of which you could avoid by also pickling the memoryview strides. (In the interests of balance, I'm pretty sure this is a flaw in some of my previous answers recommending using `.base` for things too). If the memoryviews are straight views of numpy arrays it's fine though

Comment: @DavidW I'm not sure if it works in general, but when slicing a numpy-array we get a numpy array (which becomes base), so it should work fine. One thing to consider though: we should not use `self.__class__` in `__reduce__` if in `__init__` we have something like `self.data = data[1::,1::]` - because it will skip elements from data where the elements are already skipped.

Comment: @ead So: `cdef double[:,:] u = a` `cdef double[:,:] v = a[1:,1:]` have end up with different `.base` attributes, but the two numpy arrays are linked (since the arrays themselves have a `base` attribute). If you pickle and unpickle you break that link. Slicing from a memoryview `cdef double[:] z = u[:,2]` ends up with `u` and `z` having the same base so you do need to pickle some additional memoryview data too to get the shape. I think this is surprisingly hard to get to work generally